# How to compute $\int_0^x\dfrac{e^\frac{t^2}{2}}{\sqrt{x-t}}~dt$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Hi I am working through this integral

$$\int_0^x\dfrac{e^\frac{t^2}{2}}{\sqrt{x-t}}~dt$$

But I tried doing it by parts and nothing, it seems it is solved with erf, but I don't know the method. Any help you could give, or orientation to solve this integral ?. I think one possible solution is to approximate $e^\frac{t^2}{2}$ by Taylor but will be and approximate the integral.

$$e^\frac{t^2}{2}=1+\frac{1}{2}t^2+\frac{1}{8}t^4+\frac{1}{48}t^6+\frac{1}{384}t^8+......$$

Comment: are you sure about $\sqrt{\color{blue}{x}-t}$?

Comment: So $x$ is a limit *and* a term in the integrand?

Comment: Fix Taylor expansion.  Power series in $t$, not $x$.

Comment: $$\int_0^x \frac{e^{\frac{t^2}{2}}}{\sqrt{x-t}} \, dt=2 \sqrt{x} \, _2F_2\left(\frac{1}{2},1;\frac{3}{4},\frac{5}{4};\frac{x^2}{2}\right)$$

Comment: @Raffaele how did you get that?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel With *Mathematica*. I wrote the comment to help OP to realize that it is extremely improbable to get the integral with elementary methods

Comment: Yeap the problem is with $\sqrt{x-t}$. Yes in a limit and a term in the integrand. I agree not elementary, maybe the Taylor expression is the best approximation

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}\int_0^x\dfrac{e^\frac{t^2}{2}}{\sqrt{x-t}}~dt&=\int_x^0\dfrac{e^\frac{(x-t)^2}{2}}{\sqrt{t}}~d(x-t)
\\&=\int_0^x\dfrac{e^\frac{t^2-2xt+x^2}{2}}{\sqrt{t}}~dt
\\&=2e^\frac{x^2}{2}\int_0^xe^{\frac{t^2}{2}-xt}~d(\sqrt{t})
\\&=2e^\frac{x^2}{2}\int_0^\sqrt{x}e^{\frac{t^4}{2}-xt^2}~dt\end{align}$$